# Why is using LIKE %value% giving my php page a 500 code?

Tags: php, mysql

I have tried my best to google this issue and I think maybe I am just doing something wrong that I don't understand? I have a small PHP page that generates some JSON for me from a database for use in another system.

It works perfectly until I try and use LIKE in my SQL statement with the % wild card. The same query works perfectly testing in phpMyAdmin. I am a little confused.

my data looks something like this.

shop, region, mangoes, sales, more data.

I am trying to filter by region. Region currently has four values. Let's call them "My shop", "Clearance shop", "Franchise" and "Special"

I want to be able to eventually do a URL like data.php?ShopType=shops. this would bring up my query and filter for all regions with "shop" in the region

easy I thought. I constructed a quick test query.

```
SELECT * FROM `RetailSalesData` WHERE `Date` = '01/07/2019' AND `Region` LIKE '%shop%'
```

this works as expected in phpmyadmin but when I used it on my test server it was throwing a 500.

I was using $_GET to grab my values for filtering my query so I removed and commented that out and just tried the straight query in case I was going wrong there but still no luck.

if I do something like

```
"SELECT * FROM `RetailSalesData` WHERE `Date` = '01/07/2019' AND `Region` LIKE 'My shop'"
```

then it works. But then I might as well not be using LIKE and I don't get all the results I want because I am not using the % wildcard. It seems like I can't use "%" in the query in PHP and I don't understand why.

```
<?php
//setting header to json
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$servername = "server";
$username = "User";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "mangoes";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

//get the data range and type
//$ShopType = $_GET["ShopType"];

//query to get data from the table
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM `RetailSalesData` WHERE `Date` = '01/07/2019' AND 'Region' LIKE '%shop%'");

//execute query
$result = $conn->query($query);

//loop through the returned data
$data = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $data[] = $row;
}

//free memory associated with result
$result->close();

//close connection
$conn->close();

//now print the data
print json_encode($data);
?>
```

From the above code, I expect a list of my shops with their respective data filtered out for the shops in "regions" with "shop" in the region values. What I get is a 500 error page if my SQL query contains "%" wildcard using LIKE.

Comment: Check the logs for errors.

Comment: Likely not the issue, but you have `'Region'` with quotes, so it'll be a string, not the column `Region`.

Comment: If you're storing the date as a `date` or `datetime` field in the database, then your format is wrong; MySQL uses `YYYY-MM-DD` format

Comment: Issue is sprintf it will replace % with params which youre not passing .. remove sprintf and directly assign query in variable

Comment: Is `Date` of type varchar/a text type, or of type `date`?

Comment: @Ashok Gadri  You my friend are 100% correct. removing sprintf has solved my issue.

Comment: If You want to use sprintf function then you can escape % with another % for example '%%shop%%'

Comment: You never perform the fetch. Really, you should use prepared statements, anyways. Also, make sure that connection password info is on a separate secure page. Just comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your query you're using:

> LIKE = '%shop%'

however, you're passing that in sprintf function which has a special purpose for %s chars. 
%s means that you'll provide the function with a string argument for sprintf to put in place of %s and since you're not providing the argument, it's giving 500 error.

You can get more information on sprintf on:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

Comment: This was 100% correct. Than you very much. @Ashok Gardi also pointed his out in the comments.

Comment: @paranoidsystems use the code i have updated just now that will give you the results..

Answer (score 1):

don't use quote around column name and use a proper conversion for string date

```
        $query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM `RetailSalesData` 
            WHERE `Date` = str_to_date('01/07/2019' ,'%d/%m/%Y')
             AND Region LIKE concat('%', shop,'%')";
```

Comment: You may want to tweak your LIKE  CONCAT code `;-)` re quotes order

Answer (score 0):

sprintf have the issue and also you're passing 'region' as string.. and looks like this is column name

use this code.

```
<?php
//setting header to json
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$servername = "server";
$username = "User";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "mangoes";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

//get the data range and type
//$ShopType = $_GET["ShopType"];

//query to get data from the table
$query = "SELECT * FROM `RetailSalesData` WHERE `Date` = '15/07/2019' AND Region LIKE '%shop%'";

//execute query
$result = $conn->query($query);
$data1 = $result->fetch_all();
//loop through the returned data
$data = array();
foreach ($data1 as $row) {
    $data[] = $row;
}

//free memory associated with result
$result->close();

//close connection
$conn->close();

//now print the data
print json_encode($data);
?>
```

Also you are not fetching the data and looping through the result.. updated the code to fix it.